# Image spacing issue in html and css

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I would really appreciate some help with an image layout issue. I am sure it's an easy fix but I am really struggling to work out where the error lies.

I have created an ebay listing, however the second image in the first row sits slightly lower than the first and there is also an image stacking issue - I can't seem to work out why, here's a link to the listing:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/330879734229?var=&ssPageName=STRK:MESELX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1555.l2649

Thirdly I would like to implement andimage slider and lightbox like this found here:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/New-eBay-Tegan-Fashion-Silk-Solids-Deep-V-Top-Green-Red-/400404202740?pt=UK_Women_s_Tops_Shirts&var=&hash=item9c02e563ad

But I can't seem to find anything similar, any help pointing me in the right direction would be great.

Here is the code for the ebay listing:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<style type="text/css">
@charset "utf-8";
body {
font:100%/1.4;
color:#000;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: Sans-Serif, 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
#thumbnailArea {
float: left;
white-space:nowrap;    
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px 10px 40px 30px;
width: 200px;
height: 265px;
border: 3px solid #999999;
}
.crossbox {
float:left;
height:auto;
width: 1060px;
border-top: 5px solid #999999;
border-bottom: 5px solid #999999;
}
a img {
border:none;
}
ul,ol,dl {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
h3,h6,p {
margin-top:0;
}
h1 {
font-size:80%;
display:inline;
color:#000;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h6,h5 {
margin-top:3px;
font-weight:100;
}
h2,h3,h6,h5{
color:#666;
}
h2 {
font-weight:bold;
color:#36b3fa;
fontfamily: Sans-Serif;
margin:0px;
}
h3 {
font-size:200%;
display:inline;
}
h4 {
font-size:90%;
color:#333;
margin:0;
}
h5 {
color:#666;
font-size:100%;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
line-height: 5px;
}
h6 {
font-size:100%;
}
#list {
margin-top:0;
margin-left:40px;
line-height: 15px;
}
.spacer {
}
.container {
background:#FFF;
overflow:auto;
width: 1100px;
}
.sprybox {
margin-left: 40px;
height:50px;
width:890px;
}
.header {
position: relative;
width:880px;
height:200px;
}
.header-logo {
width: 1100px;
height: auto;
}
#element {
width:600px;
float:left;
height:auto;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.clear {
clear:both;
}
a:hover,a:active,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
color:#333;
}
.content {
width:280px;
float:left;
height:auto;
margin-left:0px;
margin-bottom:35px;
}
.breakline {
width: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom:2px solid #999;
}
.deliverydetails,.paymentdetails,.productdescription,.feedback,.aboutus,.termsandconditions {
width:380px;
height:auto;
background-color:#f7f7f7;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
padding:30px 30px 30px 30px;
border:2px solid #666;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.imagecontainer {
float:left;
width:525px;
}
#footer {
float:left;
width:1100px;f
ont-family:arial;
font-size:13px;
clear:left;
background-color:#36b3fa; 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
width:1100px;height:48px;
}
#footer .footerText {
float:left;
width:420px;
color:white;
margin-top:16px;
margin-left:10px;
}
#footer .footerText a {
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
#footer .footerText a:hover {
color:white;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.copy {
text-align:left;
float:right;
clear:both;
margin-top:-27px;
margin-right:5px;
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
}
.outercont {
}
</style>
<div class="outercont">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo"> <a href="http://stores.shop.ebay.co.uk/New-Horizon-Products/home.html"> <img src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/logobanner2.jpg" alt="header logo"
    class="header-logo" /> </a></div>

    <!-- end.header --><!--end of sprybox -->
    <div class="imagecontainer">
      <style type="text/css">
<!--
.Thumbnail-Image {
float: left;
margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
width: 246px;
border: 0;
}
.image { float: left; width: 256px; text-align: center; padding:0 0 10px 0; }
.image a { text-decoration: none; font-size: 0.8em; }
.Image-Gallery-Divider { float: left; width: 400px; height: 10px; }
-->
</style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
// Create the array object
var ItemImagesArray=new Array
("http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/snake1.jpg",
"http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/snake2.jpg",
"http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard1.jpg",
"http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard2.jpg",
"http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard3.jpg","","","","","","","","","","");
// We make sure the first image exists before we execute the displaying of the images
if (ItemImagesArray[0] != "") {
// Create the indexing variable
var ItemImagesArrayIndex = 1;
for (ItemImagesArrayIndex in ItemImagesArray) {
if (ItemImagesArray[ItemImagesArrayIndex] != "") {
// If we do have additional images, create the image object here
document.write("<div class='image'><a href='" + ItemImagesArray[ItemImagesArrayIndex] + "' target='_blank;'><img src='" + ItemImagesArray[ItemImagesArrayIndex] + "' width='246' class='Thumbnail-Image' /></a>");
document.write("<br /><a href='" + ItemImagesArray[ItemImagesArrayIndex] + "' target='_blank;' title='Click to open supersize image'>Click to open supersize image</a></div>");
// Ok we write the dividers here
if (ItemImagesArrayIndex == 1) { document.write("<div class='Image-Gallery-Divider'><!-- No Content --></div>"); }
if (ItemImagesArrayIndex == 3) { document.write("<div class='Image-Gallery-Divider'><!-- No Content --></div>"); }
if (ItemImagesArrayIndex == 5) { document.write("<div class='Image-Gallery-Divider'><!-- No Content --></div>"); }
if (ItemImagesArrayIndex == 7) { document.write("<div class='Image-Gallery-Divider'><!-- No Content --></div>"); }
if (ItemImagesArrayIndex == 9) { document.write("<div class='Image-Gallery-Divider'><!-- No Content --></div>"); }
if (ItemImagesArrayIndex == 11) { document.write("<div class='Image-Gallery-Divider'><!-- No Content --></div>"); }
if (ItemImagesArrayIndex == 13) { document.write("<div class='Image-Gallery-Divider'><!-- No Content --></div>"); }
}
}
}
</script>
      <div class="image"><a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/snake1.jpg" target="_blank;"> <img src="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/snake1.jpg" width="246" class="Thumbnail-Image"></a><br>
        <a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/snake1.jpg" target="_blank;" title="Click to open supersize image">Click to open supersize image</a></div>
      <div class="image"><a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/snake2.jpg" target="_blank"> <img src="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/snake2.jpg" width="246" class="Thumbnail-Image"></a><br>
        <a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/snake2.jpg" target="_blank;" title="Click to open supersize image">Click to open supersize image</a></div>
      <div class="Image-Gallery-Divider"><!-- No Content --></div>
      <div class="image"><a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard1.jpg" target="_blank;"> <img src="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard1.jpg" width="246" class="Thumbnail-Image"></a><br>
        <a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard1.jpg" target="_blank;" title="Click to open supersize image">Click to open supersize image</a></div>
      <div class="image"><a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard2.jpg" target="_blank;"> <img src="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard2.jpg" width="246" class="Thumbnail-Image"></a><br>
        <a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard2.jpg" target="_blank;" title="Click to open supersize image">Click to open supersize image</a></div>
      <div class="Image-Gallery-Divider"><!-- No Content --></div>
      <div class="image"><a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard3.jpg" target="_blank;"> <img src="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard3.jpg" width="246" class="Thumbnail-Image"></a><br>
        <a href="http://www.sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/snakeandlizard/lizard3.jpg" target="_blank;" title="Click to open supersize image">Click to open supersize image</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="productdescription">
        <p> <span style="font-size:larger;"><strong>New Ladies bodycon Midi dress - New With Tags.</strong></span> </p>
        <center>
          <img class="spacer" src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/break2pinkcurve.jpg" height="2" width="380" />
        </center>
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <h4>Ladies super soft stretch fabric midi Bodycon dress available in either Snake Print or Black Lizard print.</h4>
        <h4> These gorgeous, flattering Bodycon dresses are Brand new in their original packaging, and ready for that special occasion.</h4>
        <h4>The dresses have the following features:</h4>
        <h4>
          <ul id="list">
            <li>Snake or Lizard print (exactly as shown in the pictures)</li>
            <li>Midi length approximately 43 inches </li>
            <li>Gorgeous figure hugging and flattering bodycon style</li>
            <li>93% Viscose, 7% Elastane &minus; high quality soft fabric</li>
            <li>Available in UK Sizes 6&minus;14</li>
          </ul>
        </h4>
        <center>
          <img class="spacer" src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/break2pinkcurve.jpg" height="2" width="380" />
        </center>
        <h2>Sizes</h2>
        <h4>
          <ul id="list">
            <li>S &#40;Size 6 &#45;8&#41;</li>
            <li>M &#40;Size 8 &#45;10&#41;</li>
            <li>L &#40;Size 10 &#45;12&#41;</li>
            <li>XL &#40;Size 12 &#45;14&#41;</li>
          </ul>
        </h4>
        <center>
          <img class="spacer" src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/break2pinkcurve.jpg" height="2" width="380" />
        </center>
        <h2>Important</h2>
        <h4>As stated in eBay's policies - if for any reason you are unhappy with the item you have purchased please contact me <span style="font-weight:bold">BEFORE</span> leaving feedback. I always have, and always do, everything within my power to resolve an issue and I pride myself on my customer service and the quality of my products.</h4>
        <h4> By contacting me first it is only fair as it gives me chance to solve any issues and provide a professional and conscientious service that I set out to achieve.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="deliverydetails">
        <h2>Delivery details</h2>
        <h4>These items will be shipped in 1 working day with an estimated transit period of 2-3 days.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="paymentdetails">
        <h2>Payment details</h2>
        <h4>Payment by Paypal only.</h4>
        <h4>Unfortunately we do not accept payment by cheque or postal order.</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--end div element -->

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="footerText"><a href="http://members.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewUserPage&userid=newhorizonproducts">about us</a> | <a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/New-Horizon-Products">Visit Store</a> | </div>
      <!-- end .container -->
      <div class="copy">
        <h1>Copyright &copy; New Horizon Products 2013 &#45; All Rights Reserved.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end .container -->
</div>
<!--STARTFROOGALLERY--> 
<!--
Copyright ©2009-2012 Frooition Ltd. All rights reserved.
The following HTML, JavaScript and CSS Styling may not be used or reproduced in whole or in part, without the prior permission of Frooition.
All eBay graphics not owned by eBay or eBay associations are the property of the eBay account owner and may not be used without their written authorisation.
Any person or group of persons found to be in breach of this notice may face legal action.
**From the froo apps center**
-->
<link href="http://user.froo.com/32b8225d1d6cfce239ee302226a863f3/FCS/css/froocross.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var az = "SC";var bz = "RI";var cz = "PT";var dz = "SR";var ez = "C=";var fz = "http://user.froo.com/32b8225d1d6cfce239ee302226a863f3/FCS/js/froocross.js";
document.write ("<"+az+bz+cz+" type='text/javascript'"+dz+ez+fz+">");document.write("</"+az+bz+cz+">");var fz = "http://apps.froo.com/application/FCS/xpromo_content/jsvariable.php?key=32b8225d1d6cfce239ee302226a863f3";
document.write ("<"+az+bz+cz+" type='text/javascript'"+dz+ez+fz+">");document.write("</"+az+bz+cz+">");var fw = document.body.offsetWidth;document.write("<style>#froo-gallery-wrap { margin-left:"+((fw-600)/2)+"px; height:0px;}</style>");
</script>
<div id="froo-gallery-wrap" name="froo-gallery-wrap"></div>
</div>
<script language="Javascript">buildFrooGallery();</script> 
<!--ENDFROOGALLERY-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would setup a example on complir or a fiddle, but to answer the image issue set in the css a vertical-align:top that will align your images to the top of the container, unless you have some sort of padding. Also use of firebug will help you debug issues regarding css/style issues. Let me know when you get a sample up so I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look, I was sure its just an error I had made.

Comment: Ok Thanks cam. I will have more of a play and see whats what. Thanks for help so far

Comment: The image lightbox you can find at leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/‎, this should get you started there, and the slider you can probably just use this coin slider plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/coin-slider/

Comment: Thanks cam, great stuff! I loaded the code into fiddle and the second image aligns fine but the rest is all over the show, I think this shows there is an error i have made - unsurprising. heres the link -http://jsfiddle.net/EFZqe/embedded/result/

Comment: I definetly recommend using firefox as it is true code. Its easier to fix IE if you code in FF first. Let me know where you get. By the way, set all your images to a small thumbnail like 200 x 200, and then do a click of your href to load a lightbox of the image. It might make your process easier and your description will show up with the images.

Answer (score 0):

Here this fixed it. Try this. Edit the max-height to your desired effect.

```
.Thumbnail-Image {
    border: 0 none;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    max-height: 549px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 246px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks cam, I tried the code but not much seemed to happen - unless I did something wrong

Comment: Update your jsfiddle so i can see.

Comment: Actually I did kind of work in the ebay listing so I will have another look to see whats going on, thank you.

Comment: I have just seen how my ebay listing renders in firefox and have major issues so I wouldnt worry to much as I clearly have some other issues to fix before I should start worrying what I initially thought was a simple image layout problem lol.

Comment: Can you take snippets and post what they look like, def use adobe labs to check CB(cross browser). My thought is you may want to use ul(unordered list) and then display the li with display:inline what this will achieve is a perfect row(without tables Hurray!!)

Comment: I think you have to repost your jsfiddle with the new link, i checked your previous link and didnt see the max-height on .Thumbnail-Image by the way kudo points on proper class naming! Cheers =)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, looks like I have a busy evening! I will repost once I get things to a cross browser friendly state, everything looked fine until I installed firefox lol then description boxes disappeared and all sorts.

Comment: Here, its a slow day, this works in FF. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/KJqhQ/1/embedded/result/  I did not create the click action BTW

Comment: Awesome thanks, the text description box has moved to the left but it seems to work ok. thank you!

Comment: Ya remove the float:left on the .Thumbnail-image http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/KJqhQ/3/embedded/result/